# Is `stream` reading a consuming process in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

A `stream` is an abstract interface for working with streaming data in Node.js. The node:stream module provides an API for implementing the stream interface.

When I was learning about NodeJs `streams`, I ran into some issues where I wasn't sure if a stream was a consuming process or not

Such as, I hava a public code:

```
import { Readable } from 'stream'

class MyCustomReadableStream extends Readable {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
  }

  _read() {
    const chunk = this.data.shift();

    if (chunk) {
      this.push(chunk);
    } else {
      this.push(null);
    }
  }
}
```

And There are some different situation with different code about deal with `stream`

---

Situation 1:

```js
import { createServer } from "http";

const customStream = new MyCustomReadableStream();

customStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('Received chunk of data:', chunk.toString());
});

customStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Custom stream reading is complete.');
});


createServer().listen(0)

/*
// Output: 
Received chunk of data: data1
Received chunk of data: data2
Received chunk of data: data3
Custom stream reading is complete.
*/
```

Situation 2:

```js
import { createServer } from "http";

const customStream = new MyCustomReadableStream();

setTimeout(() => {
    customStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('1Received chunk of data:', chunk.toString());
    });
}, 1000)

customStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Custom stream reading is complete.');
});


createServer().listen(0)

/*
// output:
1Received chunk of data: data1
1Received chunk of data: data2
1Received chunk of data: data3
Custom stream reading is complete.
*/
```

Situation 3:

```js
import { createServer } from "http";

const customStream = new MyCustomReadableStream();

customStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('Received chunk of data:', chunk.toString());
});

setTimeout(() => {
    customStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('1Received chunk of data:', chunk.toString());
    });
}, 1000)

customStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Custom stream reading is complete.');
});


createServer().listen(0)

/*
// output:
Received chunk of data: data1
Received chunk of data: data2
Received chunk of data: data3
Custom stream reading is complete.
*/
```

Situation 4:

```js
import { createServer } from "http";

const customStream = new MyCustomReadableStream();

customStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('Received chunk of data:', chunk.toString());
});

customStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log('1Received chunk of data:', chunk.toString());
});

customStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Custom stream reading is complete.');
});


createServer().listen(0)

/*
// output:
Received chunk of data: data1
1Received chunk of data: data1
Received chunk of data: data2
1Received chunk of data: data2
Received chunk of data: data3
1Received chunk of data: data3
Custom stream reading is complete.
Custom stream reading is complete.
*/
```

I can't understand the difference of these four forms, Is stream reading a consuming process?

Comment: Where does the term "consuming process" come from and what does it mean? What exactly confuses you about the output? (It all looks fine to me.)

Comment: @Pointy, Thank your reply. I have get the right anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stream.Readable` extends the [`events.EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#class-eventemitter) class. When `this.emit('data', chunk)` [is called](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/streams/readable.js#L559), the Event Emitter will look for the subscribed event listeners ([source code link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/deps/npm/node_modules/events/events.js#L152)). Then it will execute those callbacks with the given arguments. Looking for the callbacks and calling them happens synchronously.

This means that the `Readable` won't wait for the other `data` event subscribers. It will immediately [call its `resume` method](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/streams/readable.js#L1138) as soon as a listener subscribes to the `data` event (more at: [Readable streams -> Two reading modes](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#two-reading-modes)). Later subscriptions won't trigger a read from the beginning; they will receive later chunks but not the ones they 'missed' by subscribing late.